# Class does not exist ErrorException in Container.php line 738:

Tags: php, laravel

I am learning laravel and got an error. Do you any suggestions whats wrong?
I tried "composer dump-autoload" but it didn't solved this problem.

> ErrorException in Container.php line 738: Class
>   App\Http\Views\Composers\CatFormComposer does not exist (View:
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/lar/furbook.com/resources/views/cats/create.blade.php)
>
> ReflectionException in Container.php line 738: Class
>   App\Http\Views\Composers\CatFormComposer does not exist

Here is my code:
app\Http\Views\Composers\CatFormComposer.php

```
<?php

namespace Furbook\Http\Views\Composers;

use Furbook\Breed;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;


class CatFormComposer {
    protected $breeds;

    public function __construct (Breed $breeds) {
        $this->breeds = $breeds;
    }

    public function compose(View $view) {
        $view->with('breeds', $this->breeds->lists('name', 'id');
    }

}
```

app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace Furbook\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory as ViewFactory;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(ViewFactory $view)
    {
        $view->composer('partials.forms.cat',
            'App\Http\Views\Composers\CatFormComposer');
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CatFormComposer` class is defined within the `Furbook\Http\Views\Composers` namespace, but you're looking for it in `App\Http\Views\Composers`. You need to pass the correct namespace to the `$view->composer()` call.